# Cannot create logs into elasticsearch cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, winston

I use simple nodejs application, which logs message into elasticsearch cloud (https://cloud.elastic.co/).

I use **winston-elasticsearch** and **winston** packages.

Application logs message successfully in **local elasticsearch docker container** but not in **elasticsearch cloud**.

I use this simple application: **https://codesandbox.io/s/0st99**

First I got error: **ProductNotSupportedSecurityError: The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch due to security privileges on the server side.**, but I fixed this just by specifying user and password correctly in **elastic.js**.

After that I expected it should work but returns this error:
**statusCode: 400.  ResponseError: illegal_argument_exception: [illegal_argument_exception] Reason: Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_type]**

Answer (score 0):

Document type (_type) parameter was deprecated:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/removal-of-types.html

winston-elasticsearch removed _type in version 0.15 and your example is using 0.8 so try upgrading the package.

https://github.com/vanthome/winston-elasticsearch/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0150--2021-02-28